# How to show the newly created Backbone model as the first item in the Views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tree, jqtree

I am stuck into a situation where I need to add one Backbone view to a tree of Views.
[image]

I am using [`jqTree`](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) to create a tree of Backbone Views. 
I am creating Backbone Views for problem or Set in the [`jqTree#onCreateLi`](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#tree-options-oncreateli) handler of jqTree.

I have a button `Add Set` which invokes following method.
The code for this is as:

```
....
add_problemset: function(e){
  var that = this, new_set;
  new_set = new ProblemSection({ ancestry: null, type: 'section' });
  this.collection.create(new_set.toJSON(),{
    success: function(model, response) {
      model= model.set({id: response._id});
      that.enable_typeahead_at_set();
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
      console.log('error! ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    wait: true
  });
  e.stopPropagation();
}
....
```

**Current Behavior:**

It is adding **new set** at the bottom of the tree i.e at the bottom of **Set Three** (in respect to screenshot).
Here, when `this.collection.create()` line executes, it invoke `onCreateLi` function of `tree` and create view the end as default Backbone collection create at the end of the list.

**Expected Behavior:**

I want to add **new set** at the top of the tree i.e ahead of **Set One**.

Please help me with the solution or ideas?

Comment: add model to collection, listen collection `add` to rebuild list

Comment: @Evgeniy : Does it send the put request to server and fetch saved model in response like create does?

Comment: 'put' will send only in update case.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your onCreateLi method i can assume this:

you should call create method with 'at' option:

```
this.collection.create(new_set.toJSON(), {
    //....
    at: 0
});
```

It should insert new model to the start of collection.